# Server hangs when trying to boot after trying to encrypt /tmp in centos 6.9

Tags: centos6, partition, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the /tmp partition on a server after it had been configured.  I wasn't able to setup up encrypt at install as it wouldn't allow for using a random key.  Instead, I created the /tmp-tmp LVM formated as ext and of a size 10G.  After I made the changes to the /etc/fstab and /etc/crypttab files, the server started to hang and I've had to use the install disk to boot into maintenance mode to try and resolve the issue.

/etc/crypttab

```
    enc_t      /dev/mapper/tmp-tmp   /dev/urandom   tmp,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=512,hash=sha512
```

/etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/enc_t    /tmp   ext4     relatime,async,nosuer,noauto,noatime,nodiratime,nosuid,noexec,nodev,rw        0 0
```

I have taken a look at the /var/log/messages and dmesg files but didn't see any errors. Can anyone assist with what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running out of entropy as the man page says.

> For example: echo -n "pass phrase" > MyPasswordFile For swap encryption /dev/urandom can be used as the password file; using /dev/random may prevent boot completion if the system does not have enough entropy to generate a truly random encryption key.

Comment: I thought using /dev/urandom prevents the waiting aspect as I've left the server in the hanging state over the weekend to no progress.